# VBA code to copy paste data from multiple source workbooks to a master data workbook (Master data sheet) based on column headers

Tags: excel, vba

My code below browses through the folder and effectively picks out the required files but the copy paste codes that I have tried did not work for me. Cant use traditional copy paste as column order is not same. Column names are same though.

```
    Sub ImportExcelfiles()
       Dim strPath As String
       Dim strFile As String
       Dim wbSource As Workbook
       Dim wsSource As Worksheet
       Dim wsTarget As Worksheet
       Dim bookName As Worksheet 
       Dim rowCountSource As Long
       Dim colCountSource As Long
       Dim rowOutputTarget As Long
       Dim colOutputTarget As Long
   
    'Variables for Sheet - Workbook Name
       Dim nameCount As Long
       Dim fileName As String
   
      Application.DisplayAlerts = False
      Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  
   '====================================
   'SET THE PATH AND FILE TO THE FOLDER
   '====================================
   
       strPath = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Control").Range("C4")
       fileName = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Control").Range("C5")
       If Right(strPath, 1) <> "\" Then strPath = strPath & "\"
    'set the target worksheet
       Set wsTarget = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Master Data")
       Set bookName = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Workbook Name")

   'set the initial output row and column count for master data and workbook name

      rowOutputTarget = 2
      nameCount = 2
   
      'get the first file
       strFile = Dir(strPath & "*.xlsx*")
      'loop throught the excel files in the folder
       Do While strFile <> ""
      
             If InStr(strFile, fileName) > 0 Then

         'open the workbook
         Set wbSource = Workbooks.Open(strPath & strFile)
         Set wsSource = wbSource.Worksheets("Details")
         
         'get the row and column counts
         
         
         With wsSource
 
           'row count based on column 1 = A

            rowCountSource = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
            
            'column count based on row 1

           colCountSource = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

        End With

  -------------------------------Need help here to copy paste-------------------------------------    
 
          'copy and paste from A2

             wsSource.Range("A3", "AD" & rowCountSource).Copy

             wsTarget.Range("A" & rowOutputTarget).PasteSpecial 
              Paste:=xlPasteValues
         
             bookName.Range("A" & nameCount).Value = wbSource.Name
         
             nameCount = nameCount + 1
 
             rowOutputTarget = rowOutputTarget + rowCountSource - 2
        
         'close the opened workbook
 
        wbSource.Close SaveChanges:=False
 
     End If
 
     'get the next file
 
     strFile = Dir()
 
  Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome!  I'm not clear on what you're trying to do or where you're stuck.  "Does not work" is vague.  Check out "[ask]" as well as how to create a [mcve] to help make it easier for others to help you.

Comment: Which row in the source files have the column names ?

Comment: Row 3. I actually wrote a code but then realized that not all files have the exact same column names. For e.g : If my Target sheet has a header 'Deep Jaya', the corresponding header in source file has header as 'Deep Jaya Menda'. Is there a way to approximately match  header names so i am able to copy paste data.

Comment: Do you want the headers from the source copied to the target

Comment: No. Not all files have the same number of columns. out of 30 column names 27-28 are exact match but 2-3 are not because of which i am not able to capture 100% data.

Answer (score 1):

Since the order of the columns is different you have to copy them one at a time.

```vb
Sub ImportExcelfiles()

    Const ROW_COLNAME = 3

    'Variables for Sheet - Workbook Name
    Dim wbSource As Workbook
    Dim wsTarget As Worksheet, wsName As Worksheet
    Dim rowOutputTarget As Long, nameCount As Long
    Dim strPath As String, strFile As String, fileName As String
   
    With ThisWorkbook
        'set the file and path to folder
        strPath = .Sheets("Control").Range("C4")
        fileName = .Sheets("Control").Range("C5")
        If Right(strPath, 1) <> "\" Then strPath = strPath & "\"
        
        'set the target and name worksheets
        Set wsTarget = .Sheets("Master Data")
        Set wsName = .Sheets("Workbook Name")
    End With
    
    ' fill dictionary column name to column number from row 1
    Dim dict As Object, k As String, rng As Range
    Dim lastcol As Long, lastrow As Long, i As Long, n As Long
    
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    With wsTarget
        lastcol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        For i = 1 To lastcol
            k = UCase(Trim(.Cells(1, i)))
            dict.Add k, i
        Next
    End With
    
    'set the initial output row and column count for master data and workbook nam
    rowOutputTarget = 2
    nameCount = 2

    'get the first file
    strFile = Dir(strPath & "*.xlsx*")
   
    'loop through the excel files in the folder
    Dim ar, arH, ky, bHasData
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Do While strFile <> ""
  
        If InStr(strFile, fileName) > 0 Then
        
            'open the workbook
            Set wbSource = Workbooks.Open(strPath & strFile, False, False)
            wsName.Range("A" & nameCount).Value = wbSource.Name
            nameCount = nameCount + 1
                
            ' copy values to arrays
            With wbSource.Sheets("Details")
                lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
                arH = .Range("A1:AD1").Offset(ROW_COLNAME - 1).Value2 ' col names
                ar = .Range("A" & ROW_COLNAME & ":AD" & lastrow).Value2
            End With
            'close the opened workbook
            wbSource.Close SaveChanges:=False
                 
            ' copy each columns
            If lastrow > ROW_COLNAME Then
                bHasData = False
                For n = 1 To UBound(ar, 2)
                    k = UCase(Trim(arH(1, n)))
                    
                    ' determine target column using dictonary
                    ' as lookup with approx match
                    i = 0
                    For Each ky In dict
                        If InStr(1, k, ky) > 0 Then
                            i = dict(ky)
                            Exit For
                        End If
                    Next
                    
                    ' valid match
                    If i > 0 Then
                        bHasData = True
                        Set rng = wsTarget.Cells(rowOutputTarget, i).Resize(UBound(ar))
                        
                        ' copy column n of array to column i of target sheet
                        rng.Value2 = Application.Index(ar, 0, n)
                        
                    ElseIf Len(k) > 0 Then
                        Debug.Print "Column '" & k & "' not found " & strFile
                    End If
                Next
                
                If bHasData Then
                    rowOutputTarget = rowOutputTarget + UBound(ar) + 2
                End If
            End If
            'get the next file
            strFile = Dir()
        End If
    Loop
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
    MsgBox nameCount - 2 & " books", vbInformation
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

### Import Data From Files in Folder

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub ImportExcelfiles()
    
    ' Source
    Const sName As String = "Details"
    Const siFileExtensionPattern As String = ".xlsx" ' maybe ".xls?" ?
    Const sfCol As String = "A"
    Const slCol As String = "AD"
    Const sfRow As Long = 3
    ' Destination
    Const dName As String = "Master Data"
    Const dfCellAddress As String = "A2"
    ' Destination Lookup
    Const dlName As String = "Control"
    Const dlsFolderPathAddress As String = "C4"
    Const dlsFileNamePatternAddress As String = "C5"
    ' Destination Name
    Const dnName As String = "Workbook Name"
    Const dnfCellAddress As String = "A2"
    
    Dim dwb As Workbook: Set dwb = ThisWorkbook
    
    ' Destination Lookup Worksheet
    ' (contains the folder path and the partial file name)
    
    Dim dlws As Worksheet: Set dlws = dwb.Worksheets(dlName)
    
    Dim sFolderPath As String: sFolderPath = dlws.Range(dlsFolderPathAddress)
    If Right(sFolderPath, 1) <> "\" Then sFolderPath = sFolderPath & "\"
    
    Dim sFileNamePattern As String ' contains i.e. leading and trailing '*'
    sFileNamePattern = "*" & dlws.Range(dlsFileNamePatternAddress) & "*"
    
    Dim sFileExtensionPattern As String
    sFileExtensionPattern = siFileExtensionPattern
    If Left(sFileExtensionPattern, 1) <> "." Then _
         sFileExtensionPattern = "." & sFileExtensionPattern
    
    Dim sFileName As String
    sFileName = Dir(sFolderPath & sFileNamePattern & sFileExtensionPattern)
    If Len(sFileName) = 0 Then
        MsgBox "No files found.", vbCritical ' improve!
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' Destination Worksheet (source data will by copied to)
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = dwb.Worksheets(dName)
    ' Source and Destination Columns Count
    Dim cCount As Long
    cCount = dws.Columns(slCol).Column - dws.Columns(sfCol).Column + 1
    ' Destination First Row Range
    Dim dfrrg As Range: Set dfrrg = dws.Range(dfCellAddress).Resize(, cCount)
    
    ' Destination Name Worksheet (source workbook names will be written to)
    Dim dnws As Worksheet: Set dnws = dwb.Worksheets(dnName)
    ' Destination Name Cell
    Dim dnCell As Range: Set dnCell = dnws.Range(dnfCellAddress)
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    ' Source
    Dim swb As Workbook
    Dim sws As Worksheet
    Dim srg As Range
    Dim slRow As Long
    ' Destination
    Dim drg As Range
    ' Both
    Dim rCount As Long
    
    Do While Len(sFileName) > 0
        Set swb = Workbooks.Open(sFolderPath & sFileName)
        ' Attempt to reference the source worksheet.
        On Error Resume Next
            Set sws = swb.Worksheets("Details")
        On Error GoTo 0
        If Not sws Is Nothing Then ' worksheet exists
            slRow = sws.Cells(sws.Rows.Count, sfCol).End(xlUp).Row
            If slRow >= sfRow Then ' found data in column
                rCount = slRow - sfRow + 1
                Set srg = sws.Cells(sfRow, sfCol).Resize(rCount, cCount)
                Set drg = dfrrg.Resize(rCount)
                drg.Value = srg.Value
                dnCell.Value = swb.Name
                ' Reset
                Set dfrrg = dfrrg.Offset(rCount)
                Set dnCell = dnCell.Offset(1)
            'Else ' found no data in column; do nothing
            End If
            Set sws = Nothing
        'Else ' worksheet doesn't exist; do nothing
        End If
        swb.Close SaveChanges:=False
        sFileName = Dir
    Loop

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
    MsgBox "Data imported.", vbInformation

End Sub
```

Comment: Hey, I actually managed to code it but then realized that not all files have the exact same column names. For e.g : If my Target sheet has a header 'Deep Jaya', the corresponding header in source file has header as 'Deep Jaya Menda'. Is there a way to approximately match  header names so i am able to copy paste data.

Comment: Sorry, I just meant to improve your code. I missed the part *column order is not the same*. But you also mentioned *column names are the same though* which is contradictory to what you're telling now. You need to exactly explain how the headers will look like. `Application.Match` with wildcards (`*?`) will find the correct headers. Maybe a good idea would be to post another question with a more simplified code, where you will learn how to find such a kind of headers and apply it to your case.

Comment: ... or maybe not: I think that CDP1802 is on the right path so you should unaccept my answer since it's not what you're looking for. No hard feelings. Don't forget to clarify the header issue in your comments.

Comment: My bad. I was told the header names are same and they are except 2 and i realised that after i ran the code. I will start a new thread. Thanks